# How can I change my Mii's voice?

Tags: mario-kart-7

He sounds like, as one guy on forum put it, "a dying Yoshi" and I hate it. Is it possible to change it? Some say it's based on the height, some say weight, some say color. Some said it's impossible. Testing all of those would take forever...has anyone here already figured it out?

Answer (score 4):

Favorite color determines the pitch of the voice. You'll just have to play around with it to find which voice you like best.

Comment: I noticed this with Mario Golf: World Tour with Mii voices. I think it is highly likely that this game is similar in that regard.